# Writing to File Error in Java

Tags: java, printwriter

I am trying to write to a file (leaders.txt) and I am having an issue with the way the data I have calculated is showing in the file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class readStats {
public static int getStat(String letter, String stats) {
    int count = stats.length() - stats.replace(letter, "").length();

    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String hitsLeader = null;
    String walksLeader = null;
    String hitsByPitchLeader = null;
    String strikeoutsLeader = null;
    String battingAverageLeader = null;
    int maxHits        = 0;
    int maxWalks       = 0;
    int maxHitsByPitch = 0;
    int maxStrikeouts  = 0;
    int maxBa          = 0;

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("stats.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    //Find out number for each category
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] parts  = line.split(" ");
        int hits        = getStat("H", parts[1]);
        int outs        = getStat("O", parts[1]);
        int walks       = getStat("W", parts[1]);
        int hitsByPitch = getStat("P", parts[1]);
        int strikeouts  = getStat("K", parts[1]);
        int sacrifices  = getStat("S", parts[1]);
        int totalAtBats = hits + outs + strikeouts;
        double ba = ((double)hits/(double)totalAtBats );

        //System.out.println("Player " + parts[0]);       

        if (hits > maxHits) {
            maxHits = hits;
            hitsLeader = parts[0];
        }


        if (walks > maxWalks) {
            maxWalks = walks;
            walksLeader = parts[0];
        }

        if (hitsByPitch > maxHitsByPitch) {
            maxHitsByPitch = hitsByPitch;
            hitsByPitchLeader = parts[0];
        }

        if (strikeouts > maxStrikeouts) {
            maxHits = hits;
            strikeoutsLeader = parts[0];
        }            

        if (ba > maxBa) {
            maxHits = hits;
            battingAverageLeader = parts[0];
        }

        //Create PrintWriter
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter("leaders.txt");

        // Print LEAGUE LEADERS to leaders.txt
        output.println(parts[0]);
        output.printf("BA: %.3f", ba);
        output.println("H: " + hits);
        output.println("BB: " + walks);
        output.println("K: " + strikeouts);
        output.println("HBP: " + hitsByPitch);
        output.println("");
        output.println("LEAGUE LEADERS");
        output.println("BA: " + battingAverageLeader);
        output.println("H: " + hitsLeader);
        output.println("BB: " + walksLeader);
        output.println("K: " + strikeoutsLeader);
        output.println("HPB: " + hitsByPitchLeader);
        output.close();
    }

}
}
```

**Output in leaders.txt**

```
Pudge
BA: 0.450H: 9
BB: 2
K: 8
HBP: 1

LEAGUE LEADERS
BA: Pudge
H: Piazza
BB: Griffey
K: Pudge
HPB: Griffey
```

**Stats.txt**

```
Griffey HHOHOKWOHKSPOOWSHHWWWWWWW
Piazza OOHHHKPSOHOOHWWHOSSSHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
Pudge HHHHKOOHHHSWWHHOPKKKKKKK
```

**Desired Output**

```
Griffey
BA: 0.462
H: 6
BB: 9
K: 2
HBP: 1

Piazza
BA: 0.833
H: 35
BB: 2
K: 1
HBP: 1

Pudge
BA: 0.450
H: 9
BB: 2
K: 8
HBP: 1
```

I need the output to display all three of the players that are associated in the file stats.txt, not just one.

Comment: Please include stats.txt

Comment: What is your input file???

Comment: How do i upload the input file? I am new to this....

Comment: You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34800375/edit) and paste its contents.

Comment: Okay updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Start the printer before the while loop and close it afterwards.
The league leaders should be printed only once. 
Move those after the loop when you have the numbers of each player compared.

```
java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter("leaders.txt");
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
...
}
output.println("LEAGUE LEADERS");
output.println("BA: " + battingAverageLeader);
output.println("H: " + hitsLeader);
output.println("BB: " + walksLeader);
output.println("K: " + strikeoutsLeader);
output.println("HPB: " + hitsByPitchLeader);
output.close();
```

Edit: Add

```
output.println();
```

after

```
output.printf("BA: %.3f", ba);
```

`printf` doesn't start a new line.

Comment: Or append instead of overwrite but that will cause issues later on.

Comment: It prints a different player when I do that and breaks the league leaders portion.

Comment: Yes, I moved just the printer up above the while loop, but its affecting the printing of the regular stats above the leaders and not putting all of the players.

Comment: You moved the println() for the leaders after the loop? The output I'm getting with this code seems correct.

Comment: Im going to update my original with a desired output, check it out in a second.

Comment: Okay I updated the part on what i need it to look like above the league leaders.